# Silverlight 4 and real 3d support

Tags: silverlight, 3d, silverlight-4.0

Will silverlight 4 have real 3d support? 
Like, porting wpf3d classes to silverlight. it would be great if they do so. I think it could bring major improvement on this technology.. look at flash3d, java3d, papervision, googleo3d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Sliverlight 4 will still only support perspective 3D. However, it's possible that papervision could be ported to Silverlight, since Flash also only supports perspective 3D.

Answer (score 1):

There are currently no announced plans for SL4 to have real 3D support to rival WPF's. But you're right, it would be really great if it was to have 3D - this would be a real game changer for Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

No it won't have Real 3D support.  Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742054/load-3d-object-in-silverlight-3-4).

Perhaps [Balder](http://balder.codeplex.com/) may help provide what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight 5 will have 3D support. They haven't really talked about the API - although it is said to be more like XNA than the 3D support in WPF. Have a look at the full feature list here:

http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/future/